# Replace duplicate entries from python dataframe and keep first value based on other column

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataframe like:

```
Code    Desc         Category
A11   Leather Material  LM
A12   Hard Material     HM
A11   Material Leather  LM
```

I would like to remove duplicates from "Desc" column based on "Code" column. Hence for the same code, there should be one "Desc": Let's consider whatever appear first.

My final dataframe will look like:

```
Code     Desc        Category
A11   Leather Material  LM
A12   Hard Material     HM
A11   Leather Material  LM
```

Comment: That's not "removing" anything though... Given your output - it looks like you want the description for a code to be the same as the first description seen for that code?

Comment: Seems like you're after something like: `df['Desc'] = df.groupby('Code')['Desc'].transform('first')` ?